# Error that text file does not exist in LiClipse

Tags: python

I get an error that my text file does not exist even though I have created it. I have also installed the networkx package. This is the code that I have written:

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.read_adjlist("quiz.txt")
print(nx.shortest_path(g,source='v4',target='v5'))
```

The text file has been created in the project:

```
v4 v3
v3 v1
v3 v2
v2 v5
```

The code should find the shortest path between the nodes v4 and v5 using the adjacency list method in networkx package which has been installed.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ajayag\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\hello\quiz.py", line 2, in <module>
    g = nx.read_adjlist("quiz.txt")
  File "<string>", line 2, in read_adjlist
  File "C:\Users\ajayag\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py", line 198, in _open_file
    fobj = _dispatch_dict[ext](path, mode=mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'quiz.txt'
```

Comment: So...does the file exist where you're running the script?

Comment: You say the file exists (where you say it is), while the computer contends it does not. I'm going to go ahead and side with the computer on this one and say the file is not where you think it is, or you're not referring to the directory you think you are.

Comment: Try entering the full path to the file instead of just "quiz.txt"

Answer (score 1):

I rectified the issue. I had created the file in liclipse but i had not given the txt extension while creating the file. so liclipse could not recognize the file.thanks a lot guys for your help and suggestions.

Comment: You can accept your own answer after some time has passed.